# Why is this date format is giving me output as null, after casting it into date type?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

So , here in this code i am getting value of date_format as null when i am trying to convert that string type to date type ? i tried using to_date (date_format(.....)) , this also wouldnt work

This is my code ,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [[23435,'12321-41421212','2023-01-17'],[23456,'qweea-aseweweqwqeqasad','2023-01-15']]
col= ["brand","dept","date"]

.withColumn("instr",F.instr(F.ltrim(F.rtrim(F.reverse(F.col("dept")))),'-')+1)\
.withColumn("filedate",(F.date_format(F.expr("substring(dept,instr,8)"),'MM/DD/YYYY').cast(T.DateType())))
```

when casting this is the output ,
filedate : date
null

without casting this is the output ,
filedate : string
12/02/2022

Comment: Quick question - are you supposed to use the dept ? say e.g. dept has a value of 12321-41421212 - reversing it and trimming it and then getting the instr value of 10 and when used as substring - it does not give a valid date output...

Comment: this is just an example ,  the exact correct format is different , I tried with every possible choices , it just gives null as output

Comment: Seems to work for me - Maybe double check the format string...Please try code `import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

data = [[23435,'12321-41421212','2023-01-17'],[23456,'qweea-aseweweqwqeqasad','2023-01-15']]
col= ["brand","dept","date"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, col)
df2 = df \
.withColumn("date_format_output", F.date_format(F.col("date"), 'MM/dd/yyyy')) \
.withColumn("to_date_output", F.to_date(F.col("date_format_output"), 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
display(df2)`